# How to launch a newly installed program

Tags: software-center, software-installation

I have just downloaded and installed Google Chrome for Linux, using Software Center. How do I now run the browser? This was simple in Windows - the program would typically be appended to the Start Menu, but there is no such thing in Ubuntu. I've noticed that stuff related to Chrome has been installed in the `/opt/` directory, but I cannot find the equivalent to a `.exe` that would launch the browser.

Comment: Press Super Button(Start in windows),search for Chrome and launch it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you successfully installed Google Chrome, click on the Dash and search for "Chrome". When you find it, open it:

[image]

Another way is to open the [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) and run inside of it the following command:

```
google-chrome
```

Next, if you want to have it all the time on the Launcher, just right click on the Google Chrome icon from the Launcher when it is opened and select "Lock on Launcher":

[image]

Comment: Its the answer, but this should be simpler. I dont understand why Software Center isn't like Android with its "Open application" link after install.

Comment: @Jorge It is simple, when you install an app from Software center, the icon jumps to the left applications panel, shows a progress bar, and when it's installed you can click it.

Answer (score 5):

There was an desktop entry for all the installed applications.It will be located in `/usr/share/applications`.Double click on the desired application icon on that folder.Now you will be able to launch that application.

Comment: I put my application's folder into `/opt/my_application`and then made a symlink to it's `.desktop` file in it's folder to the `/usr/share/applications` folder.

Answer (score -1):

In general, when you set it to install something, the icon shows at the bottom of the left dash icons, with a progress bar. When it is finished, click to run it.