# Google Chrome vanished from applications launcher

Tags: 12.04, launcher, google-chrome

I just installed Ubuntu yesterday, after using Windows exclusively since 1995. Today I downloaded Google Chrome because that's my favorite web browser. I followed the directions at [How to launch a newly installed program](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429481/how-to-launch-a-newly-installed-program) to launch Chrome and lock it to the Launcher. Unfortunately ... after closing my laptop for an hour, I've come back to find

1. Chrome is no longer locked to the Launcher

   and
2. I cannot launch Chrome at all, not even from Dash.

What must I do to make Chrome permanently show up on the Launcher, and get it working again?

Comment: What happens if you open Terminal and launch `google-chrome` from there?

Comment: I know this is pathetic, but I still haven't figured out what everyone means when they refer to "Terminal." :-(

Comment: Search for it in the Dash.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for that, Danatela! Now I can launch Chrome. :-)

So now if I can just get my other issues resolved (Software Center won't launch so that I can use Wine), I'll be a very happy ex-Windows-user... :-)

Comment: If my answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or search for "Terminal" in the Dash) and write:

```
google-chrome &
```

This should work, otherwise it will show the problem. If it launches, you can lock it's icon on the launcher just by moving it towards (I usually place it above Firefox).